# Use mutool / mpdf to render pdf documents in doc-view mode in Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, docview

Since I feel that ghostscript is buggy on my surface laptop (at least its not working properly for doc-view in emacs with the pdf-Documents I want view; its beamer.pdf created with org-mode-beamer with complex huge pictures integrated; doc-view works but every time I want to view a slide with a complex picture, this nasty gsview64c.exe repeatedly hangs up) I would like to change to mupdf. Unfortunatly I cannot figure out how to do this.

I couldnt find any useful resources online explaining how to use mutool for pdf-rendering / pdf->png conversion.

I guess that I have to adapt  `doc-view.el`!? 
The variable `doc-view-pdfdraw-program` contains the String `"mudraw"`, which definitely is not the correct name in a Windows system. This variable is defined in `doc-view.el` as follows:

```
(defcustom doc-view-pdfdraw-program
  (cond
   ((executable-find "pdfdraw") "pdfdraw")
   (t "mudraw"))
  "Name of MuPDF's program to convert PDF files to PNG."
  :type 'file
  :version "24.4")
```

SO `(executable-find "pdfdraw")` evaluates to `false` on my system an `"mudraw"` is chosen as return vaulue, which doesnt work either on the windows platform (Win 10).

After installing mupdf on Windows the command name is definitely not `mudraw` but it's `mutool draw`. I tried to replace `(t "mudraw")` by `(t "mutool draw)` but it still doesnt work for the pdf-Files I have.

Is there anybody out there who already integrated Windows' `mutool draw` as a png rederer?

Answer (score 1):

It should just work as long as `doc-view-pdfdraw-program` either contains the absolute file name of the mudraw executable, or the executable can be found in `exec-path`.

If that is the case, then `doc-view-pdf->png-converter-function` should automatically default to the proper function, i.e. `doc-view-pdf->png-converter-mupdf`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since I work with Windows 10 with an Ubuntu-Subsystem integrated, I guess that there are 3 Options: 1. Install mupdf-tools via `sudo apt install mupdf-tools` in the Windows bash; 2. install mudf-tools via cygwin (maybe not advisable, since my emacs bases on mingw32) 3. Use mupdf for WIndows / mutool.. Does anyone have the experience whats best?

Answer (score 1):

`mutool.exe` is enough to view PDF in Emacs,

1. put `mutool.exe` in `.exec-path`.
2. `doc-view-mode-p` function always return `nil` for `'pdf` TYPE.
   you need to let `doc-view-mode-p` return `t` for `'pdf`.

   ```
   (defadvice doc-view-mode-p (after doc-view-mode-p-after compile)
     "fix: the builtin `doc-view-mode-p' does not support mupdf."
     (when (eq 'pdf (ad-get-arg 0))
       (setq ad-return-value t)))
   ```
3. make `mudraw.bat` and `pdfinfo.bat` in your `.exec-path`

   `mudraw.bat`

   ```
   @echo on
   mutool draw %*
   ```

   `pdfinfo.bat`

   ```
   @echo on
   mutool info %*
   ```
4. see [on-docview-autoload.el](https://github.com/junjiemars/.emacs.d/blob/cc/config/on-docview-autoload.el) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question, but pdf-tools now works on windows without problems. It works very well with interleave-mode.

I followed the compilation instructions under https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools using msys2 (no cygwin needed).

I had some problems getting pdf-tools to find epdfinfo.exe (the file created by the compilation step above), in the end, I manually copied epdfinfo.exe into the pdf-tools folder. Also you need to make sure that all the dlls are in the path, e.g. libcairo, libpng, zlib, imagemagick, libpoppler etc.